# How can i partition the grid colums?

Tags: wpf, layout, windows-phone-7

I have a grid with 4 partitions.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Now for equal partitioning we can use this,

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

But my requirement is to partition with ratio.
How can i make it possible with ratio namely 1:3:1.3:1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close!

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.7*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

An integer can precede a star to make a weight one (eg. 3*). See [MSDN: ColumnDefinition.Width Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.width%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), Section Syntax > XAML Values > Star Sizing.

In your case, I suggest using 3:9:4:5 as an approximation of 1:3:1.3:1.7. You may also use 10:30:13:17 if you wish to.

Here's an example taken from [MSDN: Grid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Why multiplying the ratios? They can be used as is.

Comment: @KooKiz I never tried this. But MSDN says 'integer'. Maybe you are right.